# DRF-Object of type ManyRelatedManager is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I am trying to post many-to-many fields data, it returns Object of type ManyRelatedManager is not JSON serializable.

## models

```
class Professionals(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key = True, related_name='professional')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profilePicture = models.ImageField(upload_to='professional/profiles', default='default_img.png')
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
```

## serializer

```
class ProfessionalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profilePicture = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, use_url='professional/profiles', required=False)
    skill = SkillSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Professionals
        fields = fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'profilePicture', 'skill']
```

## views

```
class ProfessionalProfileUpdateView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,IsProfessionalUser,)
    
    def put(self, request):

        serializer = ProfessionalSerializer(data=request.data, instance=request.user.professional)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            professional = serializer.save()
            professional.save()
            data['skill'] = professional.skill

            return JsonResponse({
                'message': "your profile hans been updated",
                "success" : True,
                "result" : data,
                "status" : status.HTTP_200_OK
            })
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

posting data using postman

```json
{
    "first_name":"jhon",
    "last_name":"doe",
    "skill":[{
        "id":1
    }],

}
```

Comment: `data['skill'] = professional.skill` can not work, since `professional.skill` is a manyrelated manager. You should let the serializer do the job, or JSON serialize it yourself somehow.

Comment: Since you set `SkillSerializer` to `read_only=True`, you are not really updating anything on skill. But if you want to return the serialized instance, you can use `ProfessionalSerializer(professional).data` in your `JsonResponse` result.